# Why my anaconda channels don't have the package which I want

Tags: anaconda

I want to install trochcpu & torchfile for my conda environment, but the error is the channels don't host the packages. I don't know why?

```py
Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

In China, useful Anaconda channels are very rare. I have changed my channels three times, but it doesn't work.